# Show tooltip on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the accessible tooltip working on hover. https://jsfiddle.net/lakenney/c1rogqxw/

```
<!-- Alert -->
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info gly-radius" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Click any question mark icon to get help and tips with specific tasks" aria-describedby="tooltip">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Click any question mark icon to get help and tips with specific tasks</span>
 <!-- Alert -->
</button>
```

Now I want to get it to work on Click. I'm following Julien Vernet's example except that I added accessibility markup. https://themeavenue.net/show-hide-element-onclick-using-boostrap-jquery/
... oh and I'm using button instead of href

This is what I have so far:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info gly-radius" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Click any question mark icon to get help and tips with specific tasks" aria-describedby="tooltip">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Click any question mark icon to get help and tips with specific tasks</span>
  <!-- Alert -->
</button>

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').click(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var target = $(this).attr('href');
       $(target).toggleClass('hidden show');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lakenney/c1rogqxw/4/

Comment: When asking a question, please describe the current behavior and/or error as well as the desired behavior.

Answer (score 7):

Add the ["trigger" option](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#options) to your original code:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ trigger: 'click' });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xL4r057b/)

---

In your second fiddle, you are no longer calling `.tooltip()` on the button element. You must call that function to instrument the tooltip. By default the tooltip is triggered by hovering over the button. You can change that by providing an `options` object to the call to `.tooltip()`. Specifically, you can include the "trigger" option.

Comment: I was not aware of 'trigger' ... very elegant!

Comment: I noticed that the tooltip doesn't hide itself if you don't click inside it. Any way around it?

Comment: this works fine for me, but the tooltip stays there itself . Ideally it should disappear after a second.  What should i need to do to hide it after a second,  is there any way to set time for that ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do popover instead of tooltip

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info gly-radius" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Click any question mark icon to get help and tips with specific tasks" data-content="Click any question mark icon to get help and tips with specific tasks" aria-describedby="tooltip">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Click any question mark icon to get help and tips with specific tasks</span>
  <!-- Alert -->
</button>
```

Js code

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

here is the updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/c1rogqxw/5/